# How To Combine Multiple Queries In ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I am encountering an issue trying to correctly combine elastic search queries, in SQL my query would look something like this:

```
Select * from ABPs where (PId = 10 and PUId = 1130) or (PId = 30 and PUId = 2000) or (PlayerID = '12345')
```

I can achieve each of these by themselves and get correct results.

Query A) (PId = 10 and PUId = 1130)
translates to

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "PId": "1366"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "PUId": "10"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Query B) (PId = 10 and PUId = 1130)
translates the same as above just with different values

Query C) (PlayerID = '12345')
translates to

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "PlayerUuid": "62fe0832-7881-477c-88bb-9cbccdbfb3c3"
    }
  }
}
```

I have been trying to figure out how to get all of these into the same ES search query and I am just not having any luck at all and was hoping someone with more extensive ES experience would be able to give me a hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of [Bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) using `should`(Logical OR) and `must`(Logical AND) clause.

Below is the ES query representation of the clause `Select * from ABPs where (PId = 10 and PUId = 1130) or (PId = 30 and PUId = 2000) or (PlayerID = '12345')`

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "PId": "10"
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "PUId": {
                    "value": "1130"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "PId": "30"
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "PUId": "2000"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "PlayerId": "12345"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Note that I'm assuming the fields PId, PUId and PlayerId are all of type `keyword`.

Comment: This definitely gets me closer, however the only results that are coming back are from the PId and PUId matches, I am not getting any matches on PlayerID. PlayerID is a keyword, the other fields are both integer fields.

Comment: Ok, I was able to get it by changing the PlayerID search to use a match, thank you!!

Comment: That's strange. Could you please check as I've used `PlayerId` and not `PlayerID`. Note the difference in both of them.

Comment: @Sirena Glad I could help. Feel free to accept the answer by selecting the right arrow mark on the left and/or upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap all your queries into a `should`-clause of a `bool`-query which you put in the `filter`-clause of another top-level `bool`-query.

Pseudo-code (as I’m typing on a cell phone):

```
“bool”: {
  “filter”: {
    “bool”: {
      “should”: [
        {query1},
        {query2},
        {query3}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

In a `bool`- query made up of only `should`-clauses, will make it a requirement that at least one of the queries in the `should`-clause has to match (`minimum_should_match`-will be in such a scenario).

**Update with the actual query (additional explanation):**

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {"bool": {{"must": [ {"term": {"PId": "10"}},{"term": {"PUId": "1130"}} ]}}},
            {"bool": {{"must": [ {"term": {"PId": "30"}},{"term": {"PUId": "2000"}} ]}}},
            {"term": {"PlayerId": "12345"}}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The example above is wrapping your actual `bool`-query in a `filer`-clause of another top-level `bool`-query to follow best-practices and guarantee for a better performance: whenever you don't care about the score, especially when it's always about exact-matching queries, you should put them into `filter`-clauses. For those queries Elasticsearch will **not** calculate a score and therefore can even potentially cache the results of that query for even better performance.